# Determining the maximum intervall of existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody explain to me the concept of an intervall of existance/interval of validity? Is it basically the domain of my differential equation?

I tried to look it up and I came across this [site](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IoV.aspx)

In the article it says:

> Consider the following IVP
>
> $$y'+p(t)y=g(t); \space \space y(t_0)=y_0$$
>
> ...if the interval in the theorem is the largest possible interval on
>   which $p(t)$ and $g(t)$ are continuous then the interval is the interval
>   of validity for the solution. This means, that for linear first order
>   differential equations, we won't need to actually solve the
>   differential equation in order to find the interval of validity.
>   Notice as well that the interval of validity will depend only
>   partially on the initial condition. The interval must contain $t_0$, but
>   the value of $y_0$, has no effect on the interval of validity.

Suppose I have the following linear first order differential equation:

$$tx'(t)+3x(t)=-\frac{1}{t^2+1}, \space \space \space \space x(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\iff x'(t)+\frac{3x}{t}x(t)=-\frac{1}{t^3+t}$$

So in this case $p(t)=\frac{3x}{t}$ and $g(t)=-\frac{1}{t^3+t}$

For $p(t)$ I get the intervall $(-\infty,0) \cup(0,\infty)$

For $g(t)$ I get the intervall $(-\infty,0) \cup(0,\infty)$

Since my intervall must contain $1$ the maximum intervall of existance is $(0,\infty)$

Is this correct?

How can I do this for nonlinear differential equations like:

$x'(t)=e^{x(t)}\cos(t); \space x(0)=x_0$

$x'(t)=c\cdot x(t) \cdot (1-x(t)); \space x(0)=x_0$

Is the (maximum) intervall of existance only something that makes sense when talking about initial value problems?

Comment: Think of a differential equation as a constraint on some space of solutions. A solution has a domain (a time interval) and satisfies the differential equation on that domain. The domain may not be all of $\mathbb{R}$, for example, but a small interval. It may be possible to 'extend' the solution to a larger domain. If there is a domain that cannot be extended, then it is a maximal interval of existence/validity for the solution.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then I should be looking at the domain of my solution and not at the domain of my original differential equation, right?

Comment: Well, yes, except that the domain of the solution is necessarily contained in the domain of definition of the equation.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: It is true in a vacuous sort of way: The solution is a solution to the differential equation. If the differential equation is not defined the the solution is meaningless.

Comment: Hmm. So it seems to me that the site is wrong in saying that I should be looking at the domain of the diff. equation and not at the solution. Is what I calculated wrong?

Comment: Well, in this case, since the system is linear, and the $p,q$ are 'nice', a solution will be defined as long as $p,q$ are. Hence you need to find the largest interval containing the starting time for which $p,q$ are defined.

Comment: So I would have to use a different "method" for non-linear equations, right? So in the case of the two non-linear diff. equations that i meantioned, do I look at the solution for the domain?

Comment: Yes. For example, $y' = y^2$ has solutions that blow up in finite time (depending on initial condition).

Comment: So for the second nonlinear diff. equation I get $\frac{e^{ct}}{e^{ct}+k_1}$ How would I determine the intervall of existance from that?

Comment: If the equations are well defined for all $t$ and the above is a solution, then the solution is defined for all $t$ (for this specific equation). I'm a little surprised at the solution (I haven't checked it).

Comment: The second non-linear equation is the logistic equation. If $k_1$ is negative, then this function has a pole where the solution ends (solutions must be continuously differentiable on their domain of definition).

Comment: @LutzL Thanks. Are you talking about this equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function? I have never seen/worked with this function but it seems like it is defined for all real values of x. Does this mean my interval of existance is also $\mathbb R$? I am still not entirely sure what does interval tells me.

Comment: Yes, this function. It is not the standard logistic, but a parametrized form, in this case a time-scaled version. Unlimited existence is only guaranteed if the derivative of $f$, i.e., $f_x=c(1-2x)$, and thus the function values remain bounded. By the location of the stationary points, this happens if the initial value is inside the interval $[0,1]$. For large $|x(t)|$, the equation looks like $x'=-cx^2$ and this non-linear feedback leads to dynamic blow-up, it may require going backwards in time to reach the pole, but still the solution is not defined on the whole of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @LutzL So the intervall of existence is the domain of my solution? I am sorry if I keep asking this but it is not at all clear to me if the maximum interval of validity or maximum interval of existance relates to the domain of the solution or the domain of the differential equation.

Comment: The maximal solution is the solution with the largest domain. Or the domain of existence is the largest domain of any solution. Remember that the usual form of Picard-Lindelöf only gives you the existence of a very local solution, and that you glue together a multitude of these local solutions patches to obtain the maximal solution. (And if you compare this to counting angels dancing on a needle head, you are not entirely wrong.)

Comment: So basically I am getting a solution around my inital value $x(0)=x_0$ and I want to check if this solution can be continued "forever" and not just around x(0)?

Comment: @LutzL Also, this is the first time I see the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. Seems pretty complicated so I might need some time to read into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize some of the comments: The existence and uniqueness theorems for solutions of the functional equation $\dot x=f(t,x)$ say:

- Peano: If $f$ is continuous on some domain $D$, then every IVP with initial value in $D$ has a local solution (not necessarily unique).
- Picard-Lindelöf: If $f$ is continuous in $D$ and has a Lipschitz constant in direction $x$ for all of $D$, then local solutions exist and are unique.
- Cauchy-???: If $f$ is continuous in $D$ and is continuously differentiable in direction $x$, then local solutions exist and are unique.

The maximal solution statement essentially is that the solutions can be continued to the boundary of $D$ (or infinity, if that part of the boundary does not exist).

The Cauchy theorem is the most practical. Locally it is a consequence of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, globally it is less restrictive (for differentiable ODE functions). Differentiability is often easier to check than bounding the difference quotient.

Linear ODE with continuous coefficients (almost) trivially satisfy the Lipschitz condition of Picard-Lindelöf. Since there is no boundary in $x$ direction, the domain of the maximal solution is determined by the continuity intervals of the coefficients.

In the manual solution of ODE, there is no difference of local and global solutions. The expression for the local solution is also the expression for the extension. In some cases, the expression for the solution contains singularities that may or may not be connected to singularities of the ODE function. The domain of the maximal solution ends at such a singularity, even if the expression gives values beyond.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I actually get what this is all about.