# Find the maximal interval where this IVP has unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP

$t\dfrac{dy}{dt} = t + \left|y\right|$, where $y(-1) = 1$, I need to find the largest interval where this has a unique solution.

Here, if I consider $f(t,y) = 1 + \dfrac{\left|y\right|}{t}$ then  there exist a rectangle
$\left|t+1\right| \le a$, $\left|y-1\right| \le b$ where this $f$ is continuous.

Also, $f$ is Lipchitz Continuous, in this given rectangle, so now by Uniqueness and Existence theorem we get an interval

$\left|t + 1\right|\le h $ where $h = \text{min}(a, b/M)$, $M = \text{max f}$ in the given domain.

Here, I am stuck as I don't get how to compute the maximum of this function on this domain.

The answer provided is $(-\infty,0)$ but I am clueless how to reach this interval ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

On every domain $(t,y)\in[-b,-a]\times \Bbb R$ with $0<a<1<b<\infty$ you have $L=\frac1a$ as constant in the Lipschitz condition, which holds globally on that domain. This implies that the IVP has a solution on the interval $[-b,-a]$. By the uniqueness part of the theorem, this solution can be uniquely extended to any larger interval of this type. The union of intervals of this type is $(-\infty,0)$.

- [Determining the maximum intervall of existence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285179/determining-the-maximum-intervall-of-existence)
- [Picard-Lindelöf theorem variations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926900)
- [Globally Lipschitz implies solutions exist for all time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236413/globally-lipschitz-implies-solutions-exist-for-all-time)
- [Questions about the Picard–Lindelöf theorem for an ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347599)
- [Showing Global Lipschitz $\implies$ Global Solution ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448107/showing-global-lipschitz-implies-global-solution)

Comment: I think you also need to show you can't extend to include $0$ (which is easy).  Picard-Lindelof etc. are all sufficient conditions to guarantee existence and uniqueness, not necessary.

Comment: The line $t=0$ is not in the domain of the ODE as the ODE function is not defined there, and even if a definition were added, it would not be continuous there.

Comment: The equation exists at $t=0$, but it is not an ODE there in the sense of the usual existence theory.

Comment: To complete: the equation $ty'=t+\lvert y\rvert$ exists at $t=0$ provided $y$ is differentiable at $0$ (and this would force $y(0)=0$).  But the one-sided derivative $(D^-y)(0)$ blows up with our $y(t)=t\log(-t)-t$, $t<0$, so although $y(t)$ can be extended continuously up to the boundary $0$, the original DE $ty'=t+\lvert y\rvert$ does not.  Hence the answer $(-\infty,0)$.