# division by zero ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

This is from my introductory calculus textbook.
I searched for this theorem but it seems like it is beyond this level.

So I want to know, when does this "uniqueness theorem" apply?

Is there a way of dealing with dividing both sides like this without using this "uniqueness theorem"?

Comment: It is probably referring to the Picard’s Theorem. But for now, I think for a beginner you can put the dividing by zero matter aside and proceed as usual.

Comment: Summaries of the theorem and its variants: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1286237/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3942088/115115 (and wikipedia, any textbook on ODE,...) For an extensive discussion of the basic structure of this theorem see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587806/picards-existence-theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the assumptions for uniqueness (continuity and smoothness or a Lipschitz condition) are satisfied on the domain of the ODE, then the resulting local uniqueness property extends globally to any solution as long as it stays inside the domain. This is because for a solution to branch into two different ones, there has to be a branch point. But that is impossible as the local uniqueness at that point prevents exactly that branching.

---

There is a way to deal with this DE without division that is called "integrating factor". For linear DE it often comes in the form of an exponential, so try $y(x)=u(x)e^{v(x)}$
$$
u'e^v+uv'e^v=x^2ue^v,
\\
u'=(x^2-v')u.
$$
As now two functions are used to parametrize one function, some functional relation is free. So it is possible to demand $v'(x)=x^2$, $v(x)=x^3/3$, which has the consequence of $u'=0$, so that $u(x)=C$. The case $C=0$ is included in this approach.

Comment: I have been assuming the uniqueness theorem, and it worked well until I came cross this: y dy/dx = y - y^2. So I want to know for what kinds of differential equations it is OK to use that theorem, and is there a way of solving this？

Comment: If the ODE is in normal form and the right-side function smooth, then the uniqueness applies. In your example, you get $y=0$ or $y'=1-y$, which is easily solvable.

Comment: Do you mean either y = 0 for all x, or dy/dx = 1 - y where y is not zero, for all x? There clearly are solutions where y = 0 for some x, e.g. y = 1-exp(-x).

Comment: If you have continuous functions whose product is zero, then the domain decomposes into segments where one of the factors is zero. It is possible to switch factors at the boundaries where both factors are zero. Here that will however result in a function that is not continuously differentiable, not a solution of an ODE.